# How to upload images to picasa web album as "Web address (URL)"?

Tags: url, image, upload, picasa

The Web album http://picasaweb.google.com has only the option to browse images from disk. What if I do not have images/photos on disk and I don't want to download image.

If I know the URL of the image, can I avoid the round-trip of downloading and then uploading back to "Picasa web album" ??